# XMLNS issue in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

having issue to select value for

```
create table #XMLTest
    (ItemXML xml)


insert into #XMLTest (ItemXML) values ( 
'<MessageType xmlns="ss"> <Subject>sub</Subject> </MessageType>'
)

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('ss' as x)

SELECT 
   ItemXML.query('(/x:MessageType/Subject)') 
FROM 
   #XMLTest 

drop table #XMLTest
```

Comment: <MessageType xmlns="ss">    
    <Subject>sub</Subject>
</MessageType>

Comment: @Vijah Shah please ensure that your question is formatted and tagged correctly :)

Comment: What's with the `mysql` tag if this is SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subelements are also in the name space

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('ss' as x)
SELECT 
   ItemXML.query('(/x:MessageType/x:Subject)') 
FROM 
   #XMLTest
```

Comment: thanks for that quick and is there anyway to get just "sub" value

Answer (score 0):

This is what I go with:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('ss' as x)
SELECT 
   ItemXML.query('(/x:MessageType/x:Subject)').value('.','varchar(20)')
FROM 
   #XMLTest
```